# SOAP response NULL in PHP 5.4 but valid in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

This class works great in PHP 5.2 but in PHP 5.4 the __doRequest method in the private function callMethod returns NULL.

As a result the output of the script is "NULL SOAP RESPONSE"

See the full class below

```
<?php
class ipm
{
    //BEGIN VARIABLES
    public $soapVersion;
    public $soapLocation;
    public $soapContext;
    public $soapParameters;
    public $soapClient;
    public $soapCookies;
    public $soapService;

    const groupID = '104362395629'; //MAIN GROUP NUMBER WITHIN IPM, NEVER CHANGES
    //END VARIABLES

    //BEGIN CONSTRUCTOR
    function __construct($soapService)
    {
            $this->soapService = $soapService; //STATUS OR CONFIG
            $this->soapVersion = '1.2';
            $this->soapLocation = 'https://webservice.domain/soap/'.$this->soapService.'.asmx';
            $this->soapContext = stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => TRUE)));
            $this->soapParameters = array (
                                            'location' => $this->soapLocation,
                                            'login' => 'user',
                                            'password' => 'password',
                                            'stream_context' => $this->soapContext,
                                            'trace' => 1,
                                            'keep_alive' => 1,
                                            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                                            );
            $this->soapClient = new SoapClient('./'.$this->soapService.'.wsdl',$this->soapParameters);
    }
    //END CONSTRUCTOR

    //BEGIN PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
    private function schemaOpen($fn='',$vars)
    {
            $tmp = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';

            if(empty($vars))
            {
            return $tmp.'<soap:Body><'.$fn.' xmlns="'.$this->schemaBase().'" />';
            }
            else
            {
            return $tmp.'<soap:Body><'.$fn.' xmlns="'.$this->schemaBase().'">';
            }

    }
    private function schemaClose($fn='',$vars)
    {
            if(empty($vars))
            {
            return '</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
            }
            else
            {
            return '</'.$fn.'></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
            }

    }
    private function schemaBase($fn='')
    {
            return 'http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/'.$fn;
    }
    private function dumpDOMnodeList($xml)
    {
            $docTmp = new DOMDocument();
            foreach($xml as $n) $docTmp->appendChild($docTmp->importNode($n,true));
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r(htmlentities($docTmp->saveHTML()));
            echo '</pre>';
    }
    private function debugSoap()
    {
            echo '<pre>';
            echo $this->soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders();
            echo $this->soapClient->__getLastRequest();
            echo $this->soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders();
            echo '</pre>';
    }
    private function soapRequest($fn='',$vars=array())
    {
            $xml=$this->schemaOpen($fn,$vars);
            foreach($vars as $key=>$val)
            {
                    $xml .= '<'.$key.'>'.$val.'</'.$key.'>';
            }
            $xml.=$this->schemaClose($fn,$vars);

            return $xml;
    }
    private function callMethod($fn,$vars=array())
    {
            $soapRequest = $this->soapRequest($fn,$vars);
            $soapAction  = $this->schemaBase($fn);

            $soapResponse =  $this->soapClient->__doRequest($soapRequest, $this->soapLocation, $soapAction, $this->soapVersion,0);
            $this->logSoap($soapRequest, $this->soapLocation, $soapAction, $this->soapVersion, $soapResponse,$this->debugSoap());

            return $soapResponse;

    }
    private function logSoap($request, $location, $action, $version, $reponse, $debug)
    {
            file_put_contents('soap_log', date('m-d-Y H:i:s')."\r\nRequest: $request\r\n\r\nLocation: $location\r\nAction: $action\r\nVersion: $version\r\nResponse: $response\r\nDebug: $debug\r\n\r\n");
    }
    //END PRIVATE FUNCTIONS

    //BEGIN METHODS
    public function GetGroup($rtGroupID)
    {
            /*
            GetGroup returns the status and some minor details about a specific Monitor.
            */

            return $this->callMethod(__FUNCTION__,array('id'=>$rtGroupID));
    }
    public function GetGroups()
    {
            /*
            GetGroups returns the status of members and depends of a specific Group
            */

            return $this->callMethod(__FUNCTION__,array());
    }
    public function GetMonitors($rtGroupID)
    {
            /*
            GetMonitor returns the status of the members and depends of a specific Group.
            */

            return $this->callMethod(__FUNCTION__,array('groupid'=>$rtGroupID,'bTroubleOnly'=>'TRUE'));
    }
    public function GetMonitor($rtMonitorID)
    {
            /*
            GetMonitor returns the status and some minor details about a specific Monitor.
            */

            return $this->callMethod(__FUNCTION__,array('id'=>$rtMonitorID));
    }
    public function MonitorView($rtMonitorID)
    {
            /*
            MonitorView retrieves an ipMonitor 7 Monitor objects's settings in xml format.
            */

            return $this->callMethod(__FUNCTION__,array('mon_id'=>$rtMonitorID));
    }
    public function GroupList()
    {
            /*
            GroupList retrieves the ID's of all the existing Group objects.
            */

            return $this->callMethod(__FUNCTION__,array());
    }
    public function GroupView($rtGroupID)
    {
            /*
            GroupView retrieves an ipMonitor 7 Group objects's settings in xml format.
            */

            return $this->callMethod(__FUNCTION__,array('groupid'=>$rtGroupID));
    }
    //END METHODS
}
/*  BEGIN GET ALL DOWN MONITORS  */
$ipm            = new ipm('status');
$ipmGroups      = $ipm->GetGroups();
if(!empty($ipmGroups))
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->LoadXML($ipmGroups);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('def', 'http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/');
    $ipmGroupsAlarming = $xpath->query("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/def:GetGroupsResponse/def:GetGroupsResult/def:rtGroup[(contains(def:status,'lost') or contains(def:status,'warn') or contains(def:status,'down')) and contains(def:isroot,'false')]");

    $numGroupsAlarming = $ipmGroupsAlarming->length;
    if($numGroupsAlarming === 0)
    {
            echo 'No issues'."\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
            unset($ipm,$ipmGroups,$doc,$xpath,$numGroupsAlarming);
            foreach($ipmGroupsAlarming as $ipmGroupAlarming)
            {
                    $groupName              = $ipmGroupAlarming->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $groupStatus    = $ipmGroupAlarming->getElementsByTagName('status')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $groupID                = $ipmGroupAlarming->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue;

                    echo $groupName.'<br/>'."\r\n";

                    $ipm            = new ipm('status');
                    $ipmMonitors= $ipm->GetMonitors($groupID);

                    $doc = new DOMDocument();
                    $doc->LoadXML($ipmMonitors);
                    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
                    $xpath->registerNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
                    $xpath->registerNamespace('def', 'http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/');
                    $ipmMonitorsAlarming = $xpath->query("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/def:GetMonitorsResponse/def:GetMonitorsResult/def:rtMonitor");

                    $numMonitorsAlarming = $ipmMonitorsAlarming->length;
                    if($numMonitorsAlarming === 0)
                    {
                            echo 'No Monitors Down Under This Device<br/>'."\r\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            foreach($ipmMonitorsAlarming as $ipmMonitorAlarming)
                            {
                                    $monitorName    = $ipmMonitorAlarming->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                    $monitorStatus  = $ipmMonitorAlarming->getElementsByTagName('status')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                    $monitorID              = $ipmMonitorAlarming->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue;

                                    echo '--&gt; '.$monitorStatus.' - '.$monitorName.'<br/>'."\r\n";
                            }
                    }
                    unset($ipm,$ipmMonitors,$doc,$xpath,$numMonitorsAlarming,$ipmMonitorsAlarming);
                    echo '<br/>';
            }
    }
}
elseif($ipmGroups == NULL) {echo 'NULL SOAP RESPONSE';}
else
{
echo 'No issues'."\r\n";
}
/*  END GET ALL DOWN MONITORS  */
?>
```

NEW INFO:

PHP 5.4 debug:

```
    Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body><GetGroups xmlns="http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/" /></soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>

    Location: https://webservice.domain/soap/status.asmx
    Action: http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/GetGroups
    Version: 1.2
    Response:
    Debug: POST /soap/status.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Host: webservice.domain
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.4.17
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    SOAPAction: "http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/GetGroups"
    Content-Length: 303
    Authorization: Basic blah blah blah
```

PHP 5.2 debug:

```
    Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body><GetGroups xmlns="http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/" /></soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>

    Location: https://webservice.domain/soap/status.asmx
    Action: http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/GetGroups
    Version: 1.2
    Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>...</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
    Debug: POST /soap/status.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Host: webservice.domain
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.10
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    SOAPAction: "http://schemas.ipmonitor.com/ipm70/GetGroups"
    Content-Length: 303
    Authorization: Digest username="usename", realm="ipMonitor@ipmonitor.com" ...

    HTTP/1.0 200 ok
    Server: ipMonitor 10.6
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 12:31:23 GMT
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Length: 99492
```

As you can see, the response is null and the authorization line is Basic vs Digest yet the code is the same?

If I try setting "'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST" then the response is void of the authorization line all together.

Comment: Have you checked `__getLastResponse()` to determine whether it's the XML response that goes awry or whether the error happens later on?

Comment: When I call debugSoap() or pass the individual methods within that function to logSoap or just echo in general, they are all empty/null/blank on the PHP 5.4 server... On 5.2 I get normal headers responses and so forth... Did something change in 5.4 with SOAP or the methods? The PHP build profiles are the same sans the PHP version (same extensions)

Comment: Added some new debug details...

Comment: I do see a `Content-Length: 99492`, so the service thinks it sends data... `__doRequest()` apparently returns nothing, but please, double check `__getLastResponse()`, what does that say? Also, you might want to omit the `int $one_way` from there entirely... It is `0` as it should be, but perhaps there's something iffy going on there.  Also, `soapVersion` should be the _constant_ `SOAP_1_2` (which happens to be _2_), not the string / float '1.2'.

Comment: I've removed the 0 which didn't help... Changing soapVersion as you've indicated throws:

Warning: SoapClient::__doRequest() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given .........

__getLastResponse() is NULL / empty / blank

Comment: Please also note that "Content-Length: 99492" is only on the PHP 5.2 server where this is already working... I'm trying to get it working on 5.4 where I get null responses... Thanks =)

Comment: The _constant_ `SOAP_1_2`, not the _string_ `SOAP_1_2`.. And yeah, content-length there is 5.2, I was a bit cross-eyed. Does something like tcpdump or wireshark report any return?

Comment: The constant doesn't seem to work either... I haven't gotten as far as wireshark simply because the code works with 5.2 so in regards to the network and the webservice nothing has changed but the version of PHP... As soon as I go back to 5.2 everything works just fine...

Comment: Yes, but we need to know whether the bug is in parsing a response, or an non-replying server, hence the question for a tcpdump. I'm not interested in _what_ is in there, I'm only interested in whether there is _something_ there. And yeah... compare phpinfo() output, line for line...

Comment: I'll see about getting a dump to pass along... I'm able to switch the PHP version on the same server so PHP.ini is the same... It HAS to be something related to PHP 5.4 but I've found nothing in the change logs/etc to indicate anything related to this... I might also try using curl on 5.4 to see if it works... soapClient is so buggy :(

Comment: Well, never had any problems with it myself (so never needed the raw XML anyway, it parses just correctly :P). You _say_ the php.ini is the same, but _defaults_ change, please, explicitly compare phpinfo() output if you've not done that already. Assumption is the mother of etc.

Comment: Well it looks like its an issue with SSL... Once I go to port 8080 for non-https everything works... It's a trusted SSL from Global Sign with CA bundle and roots installed... In a regular browser I can get to and authenticate to the service over HTTPS but neither curl nor SOAP will...

Comment: What does a `php -i | grep -i ssl` have to say about it?

Comment: Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
SSL => Yes
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.0
SSL Support => enabled
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
SSL support => enabled
OpenSSL support => enabled

Comment: 29 march 2010 -> are you sure that's the PHP 5.4 one?

Comment: # php -v
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Jul 24 2013 19:01:50)

# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: # php -i | grep -i ssl
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls SSL => Yes
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.0
SSL Support => enabled
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
SSL support => enabled
OpenSSL support => enabled

Comment: It's a mystery... You mentioned curl does not like to connect to the SSL variant either? If you set that to `VERBOSE`, does it output any information as to why?